# How to plot meridian labes without W and E signs in Matplotlib basemap?

Tags: matplotlib

I try to plot cylindrical projection map in Matplotlib. Here is a snippet:

```
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = 0, lon_0 = 180)
x, y = m(lon,lat)
m.scatter(x,y,0.1,marker=',',color=color)
```

When I try to plot meridian labes:

```
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,301,60), labels=[0,0,0,1], fmt='%d', linewidth=0.2)
```

I get labels with `W` and `E` and no values greater than 180. Ho to set `fmt` to label meridians without `W` and `E` in my full range from 0 to 300?

Answer (score 2):

To solve my problem I have used

```
fmt=(lambda x: (u"%d\N{DEGREE SIGN}") % (x))
```